# where can I download Microsoft.Samples.Debugging .NET library?

Tags: .net, debugging

It seems like a simple question, but I've searched everywhere for the library Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.  I found the reference in a code sample on the MSDN blogs, but I cannot compile my code without it.

More specifically:
using Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorSymbolStore;

I thought it might be here, but still no luck.  :-\
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CLR Managed Debugger Sample](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=19621) seems to include all the source code for the Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorSymbolStore.  Hope that works for you!

Comment: You're a life saver!  I've been searching for this for an hour!  Microsoft sure doesn't concentrate on indexing their code very well.  :)

Comment: just curious.. did you use this before or did you search for it?  How did you find it?

Comment: I searched for it.  I looked for the namespace, found an MSDN blog entry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/25/sample-pdb2xml.aspx which talked about an "mdbg distribution", so I googled that and ended up finding the sample.  If this solves your problem, please consider accepting my answer...thanks!

Comment: Google tells you that it is mentioned inside this PDF document, http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Ff%2Fc%2F7%2Ffc7d048b-b7a5-4add-be2c-baaee38091e3%2F9780735622029_DebugMSNET20Apps_ch03.pdf&ei=hwAtTvTBC-HqmAX8yPG5Dw&usg=AFQjCNG-Ol3Lm2BX01x9mrXWB5Ja5LRlPQ&sig2=Mnd9xmEZw2yRnm5U2tOvfQ