# How to read c# Debug.WriteLine as DebugView application does?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, output

I have a c# windows service outputting the current date and time every second using **Debug.WriteLine()**:

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

I am then able to read this output using the SysInternals DebugView program (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) however I want to basically recreate what I see in this tool in my own winforms application, therefore how can you programatically grab exactly the info DebugView is?

Comment: If you control the code, why do you need to hook into `DebugView`? Why not simply paste the date to your winform controls?

Comment: I am using this as a concept to hook into another service but need to prove it will work :-)

Comment: So you want the debug stream of another *process*?

Comment: Well it is a windows service and I just want to read the debug output of it.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579074/redirect-stdoutstderr-on-a-c-sharp-windows-service) do what you want?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener%28v=vs.90%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to intercept the debugging information coming from some process?

I think that [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367966/how-to-intercept-debugging-information-debugview-style-in-c) might help you, but I don't know what is the current state of the MDbg.

I have a little program that does something like this, but I do it using interprocess communication with Named Pipes, so there is a 2-way communication involved.

You could also take a look at the [Listeners property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can redirect the debug output to another stream, if it's somehow useful.

**[Edit1]**:

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812033/where-can-i-download-microsoft-samples-debugging-net-library) tells you were to download the MDbg API so you can use it within .NET applications. Then [the other link I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367966/how-to-intercept-debugging-information-debugview-style-in-c) might help you to actually get the output.

I think this problem can be tricky to solve, I solved it using NamedPipes but then both applications (the service and some other app) had to know about each other. Simply reading the Debug.Write of a process might involve some research about the MDbg.

Comment: MDbg appears to be dead so therefore would it be possible with listeners? I tried TextWriterTraceListener but it doesn't seem to get anything from the service?

Comment: This might get tricky. Actually, there are some ways to read the debug output. First, redirect the Debug output to the Console.Out stream, but to actually read the output you should create the process within your custom debug viewer.
The other option is to use Asynchronous or Named Pipes, like I did, but then you should do some changes to your service.

Comment: Another option is to take a look at the Microsoft.Samples.Debugging namespace, where you can find information [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812033/where-can-i-download-microsoft-samples-debugging-net-library)

Comment: I think the MDbgProcess is declared in that namespace.

Comment: I am very close using MDbg now i believe but i get some errors with LogMessageEventHandler and Console_CancelKeyPress from the example, +1 for effort , so close to the perfect answer!!! :-)

Comment: If you solve your problem, please let me know. I'm also interested.

Comment: Will do, seems really close but now failing with a COM error: The operation failed because debuggee and debugger are on incompatible platforms lol!

Comment: This comment section is getting long, my last bet is to change your [Build Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx). Try setting both to x86 and see what happens.